# Heroku Help - App not displaying in Browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, browser

My heroku app is not displaying in the browser and i have received the following code when i look at the log. The Heroku apps seemed to be running when i typed in the command "Heroku apps" so i am confused as to what the problem would be,  i am not very familiar with Heroku so it's best to keep answers rather simple Any help Would be great

```
FATAL -- :
2014-01-19T15:24:23.828258+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No
route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-01-19T15:24:23.827626+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.828478+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829247+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829247+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829247+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No
route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829247+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-01-19T15:24:23.825788 #2]
INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 108.27.248.8 at 2014-01-19 15:24:23 +0000
2014-01-19T15:24:23.828917+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829247+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-01-19T15:24:23.828478+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.828478+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.828258+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.828478+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829581+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829581+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829581+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829581+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829247+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829581+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.828917+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.828917+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.828917+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.828917+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829792+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829792+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829581+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829581+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829247+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829792+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829792+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829247+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829247+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2014-01-19T15:24:23.826691 #2]
FATAL -- :
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829792+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829792+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829581+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829581+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-01-19T15:24:23.829581+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'


Omrails::Application.routes.draw do
# The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
# root 'welcome#index'

# Example of regular route:
#   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

# Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
#   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

# Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
#   resources :products

# Example resource route with options:
#   resources :products do
#     member do
#       get 'short'
#       post 'toggle'
#     end
#
#     collection do
#       get 'sold'
#     end
#   end

# Example resource route with sub-resources:
#   resources :products do
#     resources :comments, :sales
#     resource :seller
#   end

# Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
#   resources :products do
#     resources :comments
#     resources :sales do
#       get 'recent', on: :collection
#     end
#   end

# Example resource route with concerns:
#   concern :toggleable do
#     post 'toggle'
#   end
#   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
#   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

# Example resource route within a namespace:
#   namespace :admin do
#     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
#     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
#     resources :products
#   end
end
```

Comment: Do you have a route set for the index route '/'? Something like `root  'static_pages#home'`

Comment: "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):" Please add your routes.rb file

Comment: @Pierre - I listed the routes.rb file above

Comment: You havent specified a root path, which might be the problem. Remove the first '#' in this code in your routes.rb file # root 'welcome#index' or put your own action and controller that you want to be the root.

Comment: @Pierre I Changed the routes.rb file and went through updating the file w/ git and heroku and while there doesn't seem to be a fatal in the log - when i type "heroku open" the browser doesn't open the landing page as it does in my localhost

Comment: Could you link to your Github repository?

Comment: @Pierre https://github.com/nreisch/omrails

Comment: did your app work locally? and please show an output `rake routes`

Comment: @Pierre now there is a routing error for localhost when i removed the # from the routes.rb you mentioned earlier. In addition, the output for rake routes is as follows: Prefix Verb URI Pattern Controller#Action root GET / welcome#index

Comment: you dont have any controller or view so it tries to find the welcome controller but it doesnt exist. Create a controller and view along with it and set it to root path.

Comment: @Pierre Thank You! Worked like a charm after setting the controller and view =)

Comment: Good, you can accept my answer below by clicking on the check mark on the left of my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have any controller or view so it tries to find the welcome controller but it doesnt exist. Create a controller and view along with it and set it to root path